# MySQL check if 1 minute has passed since a datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am trying to run an SQL Query where 1 minute has passed since a datetime.

I have tried this:

```
'2017-09-25 20:33:40' > last_check
```

but it returns the rows everytime, even though the last_check is `2017-09-25 20:33:00`

I have also tried:

```
last_check <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

but that returns 0 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with TIMESTAMPDIFF?

```
... WHERE
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, last_check, NOW()) >= 60
```

Answer (score -1):

are you trying to save the datetime to a variable in mysql?

if so.

```
SET @last_check = now();

SELECT @last_check;
```